# How to handle the key presses in a J2ME GUI application

Tags: user-interface, canvas, java-me, midp, midp-2.0

I programmed a bluetooth Television-Remote control for cellphones in J2ME using `javax.microedition.lcdui.*` (Gauge, List, ChoiseGroup) GUI-Elements.

I want the cellphone to have real-time interaction with my Television, I would like to find way to send user inputs performed with the GUI-Elements immediately (like changing the channel, or changing the volume) to the Television.

Since I want real-time interaction with my Television, I would like to find way to send user inputs performed with the GUI-Elements immediately (e.g. changing the channel, or changing the volume) to the TV.

Using `javax.microedition.lcdui.Command` / `CommandListner` and `commandAction` won't work since these need only recognize the commands selected with the side buttons. I would like to have something that can recognize any key pressed.

I discovered that `Javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas.keyPressed` can handle any key pressed on the cellphone, but I don't know how to make Canvas work with MIDP GUI elements like Gauge. They can't be added like Commands.

Do I have to figure out way to build a interface for these GUI elements to make them work with Canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a half solution myself, if anyone is interested:
"javax.microedition.lcdui.ItemStateListener".
This function can handle the states (or state changes) of the GUI items in realtime.
Its not keyPress, but this will work as well for my application.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [FAQ](http://www.j2meforums.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#How_do_I_capture_keypresses_on_a_Form.2FList.2FAlert.3F) you can't do what you are asking for. This is about MIDP 1.0, but I believe it also applies for MIDP 2.0. If it is only a gauge you need, you can easily paint it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw this can only be done using a [Canvas](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html).

Answer (score -1):

I will strongly recommend that you should either draw your Gauge-like item on a Canvas object or you follow the advice given on Dec 19 at 15:00 by "zhengtonic".
I dont know any other approach to this problem, I was once there but used the first options provided by me